# Artifactory quick search not filtering by repo

Tags: artifactory

I am using Artifactory 4.8.0 (OSS)

I have deployed artifacts to 2 repos: `libs-devel` and `libs-release-candidates`.

When I execute

`$ curl -u denham:password -X GET https://artifactory.server/artifactory/api/search/artifact?name=MyPackage&repos=libs-devel`

The response I receive is:

```
"results" : [ {
    "uri" : "https://artifactory.server/artifactory/api/storage/libs-devel/com/acme/MyPackage/17.10.1-SNAPSHOT/MyPackage-17.10.1-20170908.092803-1.pom"
  }, {
    "uri" : "https://artifactory.server/artifactory/api/storage/libs-devel/com/acme/MyPackage/17.10.1-SNAPSHOT/MyPackage-17.10.1-20170908.092803-1.war"
  }, {
    "uri" : "https://artifactory.server/artifactory/api/storage/libs-release-candidates/com/acme/MyPackage/17.10.1-24/MyPackage-17.10.1-24.pom"
  }, {
    "uri" : "https://artifactory.server/artifactory/api/storage/libs-release-candidates/com/acme/MyPackage/17.10.1-24/MyPackage-17.10.1-24.war"
  }, {
    "uri" : "https://artifactory.server/artifactory/api/storage/libs-devel/com/acme/MyPackage/17.9.3-SNAPSHOT/MyPackage-17.9.3-20170907.105908-1.pom"
  }, {
    "uri" : "https://artifactory.server/artifactory/api/storage/libs-devel/com/acme/MyPackage/17.9.3-SNAPSHOT/MyPackage-17.9.3-20170907.105908-1.war"
  } ]
}
```

I would expect that the results would be limited to the the `libs-devel` repo, as specified in the url.

Have I done something wrong? Is this a bug?

Here's the API reference (for version 4) that I followed:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF4X/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ArtifactSearch(QuickSearch)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. This is correct. 
You will be able to limit the search query to specific repositories by adding the 'repos' parameter on this rest call.
We (JFrog) are not familiar with a bug on this subject and it is working on our side (Artifactory OSS - same version: 4.8.0).
We will be interested to know if the same is working for you using the UI quick search.

Comment: Using quick serach via the UI works as expected. I can limit results to selected repositories.

Comment: When I try the same via curl, using repos parameter, it returns results from all repos, including those not specified.

Comment: If using curl, the full URL needs to be encapsulated in quotes. Otherwise the & is left off the request

Comment: Thank you for investigating - Sorry it was my fault in the end.

Answer (score 0):

If using curl, the full URL needs to be encapsulated in quotes. Otherwise the & is left off the request.

I tried using Postman and it works as expected.

Bested by quote marks. :-(